# redirect to the app in less than 3 second

Tags: android

I'm trying to develop android app to prevent the user from exit from the app only using exit button.

I'm using Broad Cast receiver, in `onReceive` check if current running app is my app; if yes --> continue, Else --> redirect to my app.

my question now: interval in receiver ( 3 second ) but the app takes 5-6 second to re-open the app, How I can redirect to the app in less than 3 second?

Code:

Manifest declaration:

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReciever" />
```

Implementation of Receiver:

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {     
        ActivityManager am1 = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        String packageName = am1.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();

        if (packageName.equals("com.XXXX.YYYYY")) {
            //continue;
        }else{
            final Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setClassName("com.XXXX.YYYYY", "com.XXXX.YYYYY.Launch");
            thisActivity.startActivity(intent);
            thisActivity.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to give provision to exit from your own app? If that's the case why do you have to use broadcast receivers? Why not try

> android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

onBackPressed() method?

Comment: no, I'm trying to prevent the user from exit from the app using home key

Comment: Then disable home key or over ride it

Comment: my device is Samsung S3; android 4.4.4 this means can't disable home key

Comment: have you tried this? @Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}

Comment: broadcast receivers wont work after android 4.0, i tried once to auto start my app it worked in android 2.3 but not in 4.0

Answer (score 1):

Refer Link : for disable the home key,menu key and back key

[How To lock home key](https://github.com/shaobin0604/Android-HomeKey-Locker)